# is there any way to swap coins/tokens through Binance spot api?

Tags: binance, binance-api-client

This is a bit theoretical question. Actually, I am developing a crypto swapping platform where user's can swap their crypto coins/tokens to another coins/tokens.

Right now, I have included 7 exchanges api, fully functioning api system. Right now I need to include Binance API for this swap.

Below are the issues I am facing right now, if you any help is provided then I can design the code accordingly.

1. Binance do not provide swapping api out of the box, instead they provide spot api which is quite ambiguous. I tried to contact their support over chat/telegram but they seem to be not interested to respond to my "silly" questions.
2. Binance just have a limited number of coin/token pairs while my application have around 50 individual coins/token.

Here is how my current swapping works:

1. A user comes to my site, he wants to swap his ETH to get equivalent BTC. API is hit to 7 exchanges and fetches the latest rates for the said pair.
2. User can select the best rate providing exchange, on next page, he will be presented a wallet address where he can transfer his ETH (to the exchange obviously) and textbox to enter his BTC wallet address to receive converted BTC. A textbox also for email so that we can intimate user about his txn status.
3. Once txn is successful, user will get BTC wallet deposited.
4. No user sign up is required in any stage of txn. It is just as simple as that GIVE and TAKE.

So the question is how can I achieve this using binance spot api. If anyone has worked on binance swapping, enlightening me on this will be great help for me.

Comment: Hi, if I understand, you want to join 7 markets, and the user selects the lowest rate, and place an order, buy right?, it doesn't make much sense for the large exchanges to provide after market exchange, as they would be losing clients who are obligated to perform a simple registration, the ideal for you would be to connect your swap to pools, Imagine a DEX joining multiple CEX, for me it would be impossible basically this is your project,

Comment: @Miguel no, this is not my project. You can check my project at https://coinbns.com. There are around 7 exchanges data I am gathering. I need to include binance too.